# ASP.NET Client Default Printer

Tags: asp.net, printing

We would like to grab the name of the clients Default Printer from ASP.NET from within an intranet.
We understand the security risks that pertain to extranet or internet applications but this solution is 100% intranet.

1. System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings appears to give me the server printers not the clients (which is to be expected).
2. WMI query approach would require us to make security setting changes
3. System.Printing.LocalPrintServer appears would only give us the Server printer (but not clients) based on the description of the class
4. System.Printing.PrintServer looks like it might work if I pass it the computer name (I will try this after this post).
5. DirectorySearcher approach which queries ActiveDirectory. We are successful using that for getting a list of shared printers on a persons profile.

However, the kicker in all those approaches is that when I do get a default printer returned its the default printer of the OS on the machine NOT the default printer of the users default profile.

My gut tells me what we want to do is not possible with out running code on the client either directly or via the browser. I think the user profile part is what kills our chances

Comment: Web browsers only have minimal access to the OS for security reasons, so this is most likely not possible.

Comment: Sounds like fun, a website could print an ad directly on the client printer. What could possibly go wrong...